# Does the Java for each loop return a reference, or a reference copy?

Tags: java, reference, foreach

I know that Java doesn't really use exact pass by reference, but rather pass by reference copy. This is why a swap function that just tried to swap references wouldn't work in Java. Does a for-each loop do this as well? For instance, given the following code...

```
for (Constraint c : getLeafNodes(constraintGraph)){
    c = new Constraint();
}
```

...I want to go through a recursively defined tree-like structure, and find all leaf nodes. Each leaf node needs to be replaced with a new, empty node. Will this do what I expect it to, or will it simply set a copy of the reference to each leaf node to a new node?

I wrote a similar method on another piece of code that passed unit tests, which makes me think a for-each loop uses references, not reference copy, but our code quality software flagged this as a dead-store to a local variable, major error.

Thanks.

Comment: The for-each loop doesn't return anything (to whom?). Your question doesn't match the title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It won't do either.  That's similar to saying

```
Object c = getObject();
c = new Object();
```

All you've done is change what `c` refers to.  This wouldn't work even if Java supported true pass-by-reference

Comment: D'oh, you're right. I don't know what I was thinking. I should be retrieving the parent of each leaf, then calling some sort of parent.setChild(new Constraint()) method. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: **reference-copy**

When you assign an iterator's variable, it will not be propagated to the collection. See the iterator as a read-only access to the list.

Java's for loop works exactly as C#'s `for-each` loop, in which `while` the `Enumerator` can `moveNext` it will assign to the local variable the `Current` element

Answer (score 0):

No it will not do what you expect. `c` is a local variable which refers/points to an element in the collection returned by `getLeafNodes`. Java does not have the *reference* concept you mention, everything is a *reference copy*. If you know e.g. C or C++, think of object variables in java as *pointers* not references.